# Incorrect CSS fieldset border color

Tags: html, css, border, fieldset

I have a fieldset that needs CSS styling. And I want the color to be this one: #0088FF. I do this:

```
fieldset {
     border: 1px groove #0088FF !important;
     padding: 0 1.4em 1.4em 1.4em !important;
     margin: 0 0 1.5em 0 !important;
}
```

The color is incorrect, it appears as a darker shade of my intended color. Any ideas?

Comment: Web safe color of #0088ff is #0099ff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this fiddle, your shadow on the groove is making it apeer darker https://jsfiddle.net/7sud8341/1/

`<fieldset id="first"></fieldset>
<fieldset id="second"></fieldset>`

```
    fieldset {
     border: 10px solid #0088FF !important;
     padding: 0 1.4em 1.4em 1.4em !important;
     margin: 0 0 1.5em 0 !important;
}
#second {
     border: 10px groove #0088FF !important;
     padding: 0 1.4em 1.4em 1.4em !important;
     margin: 0 0 1.5em 0 !important;
}
```

And if it is still too dark try using this #0099FF for the color

Answer (score 2):

You are using `groove`, try `solid`.

If that fails, make the shade of blue a bit lighter. You can achieve this by using [Colorhexa](http://www.colorhexa.com/)

Comment: Your answer is more elaborate. :)

Comment: I just made the lines thicker so he can see what we are talking about :)